# How to add a another li container after ul container wp_nav_menu wordpress and other html tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, menubar

> Please help me custome wp_nav_menu with walker , thanks

```
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">PROJECT<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="grid-demo">
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Introduction</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Floor Plans A Type</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Floor Plans B Type</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Floor Plans C Type</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Floor Plans D Type</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Floor Plans E Type</a></div>
                    </div>
              </div>
                </li>
          </ul>
            </li>
```

> how can i add some container tag after ul tag like `<li class="grid-demo">
>                         <div class="row">
>                       <div class="col-sm-5">`

```
        <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FEATURES</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">PAYMENT<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="grid-demo">
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Playment T&C</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Financial Services</a></div>
                    </div>
              </div>
                </li>
          </ul>
            </li>
            <div class="spanLogo">aaa</div>
```

> and how can i add one `<div class="spanLogo">aaa</div>` here
>
> continue

```
            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">PUBLICITY<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="grid-demo">
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">News & Events</a></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="linkTrang">Testimonial</a></div>
                    </div>
              </div>
                </li>
          </ul>
            </li>
```

> and here > > and how can i add one a tag with image like code above ,  thanks

```
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo_paujar_top.jpg"/></a>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest you should used wp_get_nav_menu_items() function. In this function you can get separately all your menu title and url, So easily you manage your html.

Here is demonstration

`<?php $menu_item = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuId);
    foreach($menu_item as $menu):?> 
       <a class="menu-iterm" href="<?php echo $menu->url;?>">
           <?php echo $menu->title;?>
       </a>
    <?php endforeach;?>`

For more information you get here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items